# Adding columns of 2d list if certain value in a row

Tags: python

Lets say I have a 2D list:

```
mylist = [[3,4,5,'x'],
          [6,1,4,'x'],
          [4,7,9,'y'],
          [0,4,3,'y'],
          [5,1,7,'z']]
```

How would I sum up the second column where the fourth elements are the same (the letters)? Currently I have isolated the fourth elements into a list, avoiding duplicates, with:

```
newlist = list(set([r[3] for r in mylist]))
```

Which returns a list `['z', 'y', 'x']`

I want it in a format like: `[['x', a], ['y', b]..]` or in a dictionary like `{'x':a,...}`

Where `a` is the sum of the second column where `mylist[3]='x'`, which would be 4+1, and `b` is the same but with `y` and would be 7+4. So this example would output `[['x', 5], ['y', 11], ['z', 1]]`

What would be the best way to do this? Or would numpy/pandas handle it better?

Comment: it should be `['y', 11]` right since y is present in two columns and 7+4=11 where 7 and 4 are second elements

Comment: Oh yeah thanks, I mistook the x for a y

Comment: Cool! Check my answer below @rharper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it, I am using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
mylist = [[3,4,5,'x'],
          [6,1,4,'x'],
          [4,7,9,'y'],
          [0,4,3,'y'],
          [5,1,7,'z']]

#Zip all elements in the list
res = list(zip(*mylist))

#Zip the second column and character array
arr = list(zip(res[1], res[3]))
#[(4, 'x'), (1, 'x'), (7, 'y'), (4, 'y'), (1, 'z')]
dct = {}

#Calculate the sum
for num, key in arr:
    dct.setdefault(key,0)
    dct[key]+=num

print(dct)
#{'x': 5, 'y': 11, 'z': 1}

#Convert dict to list
li = []
for k, v in dct.items():
    li.append([k,v])

print(li)
```

The output will be

```
[['x', 5], ['y', 11], ['z', 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Counter (from collections):

```
from collections import Counter
result = Counter()
for r in mylist: 
    result[r[3]] += r[1]
```

You also could do it in a single line:

```
result = Counter( r[3] for r in mylist for _ in range(r[1]) )
```

or without using Counter:

```
result = dict()
for _,value,_,key in map(tuple,mylist):     # for r in mylist
    result[key] = result.get(key,0) + value #    result[r[3]]=result.get(r[3],0)+r[1]
```

or

```
result = { r[3]:sum(v[1] for v in mylist if v[3]==r[3]) for r in mylist }
```

*note that the for loops will run faster than the one liners*

Comment: Damn! Could have counted on `Counter`, and didn't knew you can use a Counter like that!

Answer (score 1):

I do prefer pandas for this purpose like this:

```
import pandas as pd
mylist = [[3,4,5,'x'],
          [6,1,4,'x'],
          [4,7,9,'y'],
          [0,4,3,'y'],
          [5,1,7,'z']]
df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
```

this gives:

```
print(df)
   0  1  2  3
0  3  4  5  x
1  6  1  4  x
2  4  7  9  y
3  0  4  3  y
4  5  1  7  z
```

Working with pandas groupby:

```
print(df.groupby(3).sum())
   0   1   2
3           
x  9   5   9
y  4  11  12
z  5   1   7

print(df.groupby(3).sum()[1].to_dict())
{'x': 5, 'y': 11, 'z': 1}
```

That's it

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by looping over each element in your list, checking the 4th spot for either x or y, and adding to some running total:

```
mylist = [[3,4,5,'x'],
          [6,1,4,'x'],
          [4,7,9,'y'],
          [0,4,3,'y'],
          [5,1,7,'z']]

x_total = 0
y_total = 0
for i in mylist:
    if i[3] == "y":
        y_total += i[1]
    if i[3] == 'x':
        x_total += i[1]


print("x: ",x_total)
print("y: ",y_total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way could be using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```py
from collections import defaultdict

mylist = [
  [3,4,5,'x'],
  [6,1,4,'x'],
  [4,7,9,'y'],
  [0,4,3,'y'],
  [5,1,7,'z']
]

d = defaultdict(int)

for l in mylist:
  d[l[3]] += l[1]

# d: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'x': 5, 'y': 11, 'z': 1})
# dict(d) to convert to regular dict
```